How to Ensure Type-Safe Querying with Drizzle ORM in a Base Repository's Primary Key Handling?
I'm building an abstract base repository class using Drizzle ORM for a PostgreSQL database. The repository is generic and works with any table extending PgTable, and the primary key is passed dynamically. Here's the relevant part of my implementation:
async findOne(id: T['$inferSelect'][ID]): Promise<InferSelectModel<T>> {
  if (!id) {
    throw new Error('ID is required');
  }

  const result = await this.db
    .select()
    .from(this.table)
    .where(eq(sql.raw(`${this.primaryKey.toString()}`), id));

  if (!result.length) {
    throw new Error(`No record found for ID: ${id}`);
  }

  return result[0];
}

The Problem:
The sql.raw(${this.primaryKey.toString()}) usage is not type-safe, which defeats the purpose of using TypeScript for strict typing. If the primaryKey string doesn't match the actual column name in the table, it will only throw runtime errors.
I want a solution that ensures the primary key is type-safe and can be correctly validated at compile-time.
Additional Context:

The primaryKey parameter in the constructor is of type ID extends keyof T['$inferSelect'].
The repository is used to perform common CRUD operations (findOne, create, update, delete) for various tables.
Drizzle ORM does not directly support operations like .where() using dynamic keys without sql.raw.

Here's the constructor for additional reference:
constructor(
  protected readonly db: DrizzleDB,
  protected readonly table: T,
  protected readonly primaryKey: ID,
) {}


How can I make the where() clause for the primary key type-safe in this context?
Is there a better approach or pattern for handling dynamic primary keys in a repository class with Drizzle ORM?

